# How to Deploy a Custom WebPartPage to a specific target site (Web)

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have created a custom web part, let's call is AppPart, and a custom web part page, let's call it AppPage, in the same solution. I changed the AppPage's Elements.xml so that it automatically contains the AppPart when the Feature is activated. This works excellent for my purposes. My problem is that Visual Studio will only allow me deploy the feature to a Site (site collection) scope and I need to deploy this page to a Web (specific web site) scope. From my understanding, this is possible to do but a configuration change has to be made by hand.

Comment: Really, a -1? Mind to explain why you did that instead of just doing it for the sake of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using powershell, specify the web application in the command.

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity <SolutionName> -WebApplication <URLname>
```

take a look at this link & do a ctrl+F for "To deploy a solution package to a single Web application by using Windows PowerShell"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: So does this mean it is not possible to do in Visual Studio? I didn't realize it would be that simple...

Comment: In my experience, deployment via visual studio is only for development purposes to a local development environment.  Once your solution is ready, package it then copy the .wsp to QA/Production/etc. and deploy as described in the link above.

Comment: I won't argue with that. I am new to SharePoint development, so this was not as obvious to me as it is now. Thank you helping me understand instead of clicking -1 like some people do.